# How do I replace specific line positions in sed?

Tags: sed

I need to be able to use sed (or anything else) to replace a *specific* line position, I'm Googleing and can't find anything (yet).

*** UPDATE ***

this is what I came up so far..

```
sed 's|\(^.\{67\}\).\{1\}||g' $$
```

yet this deletes everything from beginning to position 67+1, I want *ONLY* position 67+1 to be gone..

Comment: so you want the first character on line 67 to be deleted?

Comment: no, I want position 67 and position 68 to be gone..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first believed youd need this. This will match 66 characters `\(.\{66\}\)` and store it in `\1`, put the next two `\(.\{2\}\)` in `\2`, and everything else `\(.*\)` in `\3` it will substitute `\1\2\3` with `\1\3`, disappearing you 2 characters you dont want.

```
sed 's/^\(.\{66\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.*\)/\1\3/'
```

And then I remembered this. This will substitute 2 characters `'..'` for `''` at character 67.

```
sed 's/..//67'
```

Comment: it works, but if you don't mind can you explain it please?)

Comment: @alexus explained